# Чем отличается "метод" от "функции"

Tags: терминология

Неоднократно видел использование термина "метод" для обозначения функций-членов классов в противоположность термину "функция" для обозначения "свободных" функций нечленов. С другой стороны, в текстах о Си++, часто всё называют "функцией" и члены и нечлены.

Собственно, какова разница между терминами "метод" и "функция", почему в Си++ члены не называют "методами"?

Comment: `почему в Си++ члены не называют "методами"?` - так и хочется пошутить про потому что они ч..... но не буду

Comment: Метод - это функция, которая член класса. И это вся разница вроде)

Comment: @andreymal можно как ответ делать. терминология-faq с эпичным ответом)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я не уверен, что так во всех языках, и предпочту воздержаться от ответа. Эпичный ответ с примерами и исключениями (если таковые существуют) от кого-нибудь уверенного будет более полезным)

Comment: @andreymal А процедура - член класса тогда как называется?

Comment: `почему в Си++ члены не называют "методами"?` Называют, просто чаще их называют "функция-член класса", что по сути то же самое)

Answer (score 15):

И чего так много слов то? Все просто:

> Метод это функция класса

Метод всегда является функцией, а функция не всегда является методом.

Comment: Это как "Большой палец - всегда палец, но палец не всегда большой?" (c) ТБВ

Comment: Точно, именно так :)

Answer (score 10):

Нет единой устоявшейся техники наименования сущностей в языках программирования и каждый язык, чтобы немного отличаться от других, по историческим причинам имеет свой набор названий и соглашений.

Так как программирование пришло с математики, то начальные корни нужно искать там. А там были функции и процедуры. Функция на основании своих аргументов генерирует какой-то результат. `sin`, `cos` - яркие примеры. Функция без аргументов - вырожденный вариант и обычно это константа. В математике обычно функции являются чистыми - то есть, у них нет побочных эффектов. То есть, вызов функции с одними и теми же аргументами дает один и тот же результат.

Параллельно существуют процедуры. Процедура - это последовательность действий, приводящая к определенному результату (да, обычная программа - это также может быть процедура, хотя...). В паскале и фортране принято, что процедура не возвращает результат. Но я считаю, что это исключительно соглашение, потому что иначе нужно было бы делать как в *C*/*C++* и вводить пустой тип (void).

> почему в Си++ члены не называют "методами"?

Во многих языках 60-70 годов не было ООП в том понимании, которое известно сейчас. *С++* изначально был просто "фронтом" (то есть надстройкой) над обычным Си. Был долгий период, когда это уже был не Си, но и ещё и не *C++*. Компилятора *C++* не было, а был транслятор в Си. Видимо, поэтому там закрепилось функция класса/переменная класса. Сейчас Страуструп предлагает [N4174](https://habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/240851/), и если его примут, то грань между обычными функциями и функциями класса размоется ещё  больше.

В других языках - *Java* и семейство, проектировались, когда уже ООП был немного сформированным. От обычных функций они решили отказаться и, видимо, чтобы не вызывать путаницу, обозвали все методами. Да, потом им пришлось функции все-таки вернуть назад, но, чтобы ничего не сломать, назвали это статическими методами.

> Собственно, какова разница между терминами "метод" и "функция"

Правильный ответ - историческая. Как правильно называть сущности в разных языках, нужно уточнять в их документации.

> многие автора книг по с++ называют функции класса методами. Как быть?

Тут все сложно. Например, Эккель так делает видимо потому, что он ещё и много книг о *Java* написал. Также не стоит забывать, что многие книги мы читаем в переводе, а они "исправляют", потому что переводчику так понятнее.

> так можно ли называть функции класса с++ методами?

Это точно так же, как использовать мат/обсценную лексику в высшем обществе. Или пытаться объясниться с гопниками языком Тургенева и стихами Пушкина/Блока.

P.S. метод - слово многозначное и вполне можно услышать от *C++* программистов такое "это метод для получения данных с сервера, реализован в виде 5 функций и двух классов".

Comment: Процедуры в математике? А ссылку можете дать, подробнее посмотреть.

Comment: процедура как одно с названий последовательности действий для решения задачи. Синоним "Алгоритм".

Comment: Извините, но у вас написано как-будто "функция" и "метод" равносильные понятия в математике. Тогда как понятием математики является только "функция", а "метод" нет.

Comment: Вот именно "как будто". В математике функция может быть определена через некую последовательность действий, которую нужно выполнить, что бы получить результат функции (например, разложение в ряд). И это вполне можно назвать "методикой" вычисления или процедурой вычисления значения.

Comment: Я говорю, что "функция" объект математики, то чем она оперирует кроме прочего. Нельзя в математике назвать "функцией" что угодно или ошибиться. Вас обязательно поправят либо не поймут, так как "функция" входит в язык математики, имеет свое специальное содержание в этом языке. А "метод" таким словом не является поэтому с ним можно обращаться более вольно, иметь под ним в виду алгоритм или что-то еще. От сюда, нельзя говорить что в математике есть понятие "метод"

Comment: Я прошу прощения, совсем все перепутал, в моих коментариях выше нужно "метод" заменить на "процедура", конечно же.

Answer (score 9):

Вот определение **метода**:

> Метод в объектно-ориентированном программировании — это функция или процедура, принадлежащая какому-то классу или объекту. Методы классифицируются по применимости к объектам: *статические* и *простые* или *нестатические*; по возможности использования: `public`, `private`, `protected`.

Вот определение **функции**:

> Функция в программировании — фрагмент программного кода (подпрограмма), к которому можно обратиться из другого места программы. Функция может принимать параметры и должна возвращать некоторое значение, возможно `void`. Функции, которые возвращают `void`, называются процедурами.

Как видим, первое является разновидностью второго. Насчет того, что в C++ все называют *функциями* я не соглашусь, понятие *метод класса* тоже часто употребляется. Просто *функция* является более общим названием.

Answer (score 3):

Функция это самостоятельная сущность. Метод это часть класса(объекта) и без него не употребляется.

Comment: функция уж точно не структура.

Comment: Укажите ЯП в ответе. Вопросе пока не отмечен меткой кокого-то определённого  языка.

Comment: @KoVadim думаю под **структурой** понимается **конструкция**.

Comment: я думаю, тут самое уместное слово - "сущность".

Comment: В C#, например, функции не могут жить отдельно, они обязательно должны быть внутри какого-то класса. Значит ли это, что в C# нет функций, а только методы? Могу ли я назвать `Math.Sin()` функцией? Статические методы не требуют наличия экземпляра класса - это функции или методы?

Comment: в своем ответе я  об  этом написал - это статические методы. И они выполняют роль функций. Но называть их функциями нельзя:)

Comment: Сущность подходит больше так как обстрактнее. Все что вызвается от класса это метод, статический он или нет не важно. Язык в данном случае не имеет значения.

Comment: то есть, в с++ методы?:) все что "вызывается от класса" - это статический метод/функция. Что вызывается от объекта - функция/метод.

Comment: Везде функции называются методами, если они члены класса(объекта) =) Возможно что в каком-нибуть сообществе их называют и подругому, но классически в ООП это так.

Answer (score 3):

Понятие "метод" это частный случай "фукнции". Здесь под "методом" понимается функция-член.

Понятие "метод" пришло из языка Smalltalk на заре ООП. Вводить это понятие потребовалось для того, чтобы описать механизмы вызовов функций в Smalltalk. Процесс вызова функции в Smalltalk, в общем, делится на: посылку сообщения, выбор подходящего метода (диспечеризацию) и выполнение найденого метода. Вот чтобы эти тонкости описать потребовались отдельные понятия: "сообщение", "диспечеризация" и "метод".

Когда ООП сделали "передним краем" программирования, а Smalltalk одной из его звед, его идеология начала интенсивно просачиваться в другие языки. Smalltalk оказал большое влияние на развитие ООП, прежде всего благодаря хорошей проработке понятий и качественной "архитектуре" языка.

Причем "метод" появился не просто как "функция-член", он вытащил и представление о "сообщениях" с "диспечеризацией". Вот от сюда в Си++ и возникло стремление четко указывать что в Си++ "методов" нет, что здесь только функции-члены.

В 90-х "метод" появился в новой Яве. Но только к этому времени, от него отвалились "сообщения" и "диспечеризация", так как на "переднем крае" уже с ними наигрались, наступала эпоха компонентов. Понятие "метод" приобрело современное содержание и стало означать "функцию-член". К стати, результатом этого стало то, что "метод" таки просочился в Си++, но только, опять повторю, этот новый "метод" проще, чем тот старый на сообщениях.

Понятие "функция" в это время никак не менялось.

Answer (score -2):

Все очень просто. Метод (void) ничего не возвращает, а функция возвращает какое то значение (bool, string, int, List и т.д.)

Вот пример метода:

```
void Method(int x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);    // Ничего не возвращает
}
```

А вот пример функции:

```
List<string> Function(string[] rows)
{
     var list = rows.ToList();
     return list;                // Возвращает значение типа функции
}
```

Comment: Ничого подобного, что и функиция и метод могут как возвращать значение, так и не возвращать ничего.

Comment: В первом случае, это процедура